# Ler arquivo PDF python

Tags: python

Estou tentando criar um script que faça a leitura de um PDF identifique alguns pontos chames, na sequencia marque as paginas que se encontram essas chaves, e faça split da pagina em si. E na sequencia faça um merge assim gerando um novo PDF resumido.

```
import PyPDF2
pdf_file = open('nomefatura.pdf','rb')
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
page = pdf_reader.getPage(1)
text = page.extractText()
print(text)
```

Mas a saída fica assim:

5G=AK;"A?"BCP;<>;<.-/78.7:-1Y.,7.77-ZABT;"A?"SJB?@>?6Y-ZABT;"A?"L=>GK=*=J;K !N=="\*=J;K !N=="\*=J;K !N=="\*=J;K !5%4FHGRCGP$D6DGD54RHDG636VC3CC7C3CC7C -1+>7C3CC -1+>C3CC5%4FHGRCG%4C$8D6DGD54RHG64%CGC36G64%CGC3V56GG%6F635D7R3FG -1+>7C3CC -1+>C3CC5%4FHGRCG%44$8D6DGD54RHFR%DHV3H4R%DVC3CC6GH563GC7R3FG -1+>7C3CC -1+>C3CC5%4FHGRCG%46$8D6DGD54RH54R%VF63GG4R%VFR3CC6GR%DVC35G7R3FG -1+>7C3CC -1+>C3CC5%4FHGRCG%4R$8D6DGD54RHH6D%D653VC6D%DRC3GC6GF%4C53FR7R3FG -1+>7C3CC -1+>C3CCNO$ Pj#DDV3C4NO@  (TPj#66G3D4(*#+10,I2*0,1-#f#T02#46%5D4E6C46&Y#.-,1)2_<2bc0Y#+-#NO$ #g4kh#0#NO@  (T#gC3Gkh#,=-#Y=-#)0Z+YY+I+Y#fY#1+)2\+Y%4?LBSB?@>?<"3GAB>BR;<"?"A="Y=J="JBTG?(")'))"]F9"$H')"RB=">?J?L;@?"LBO;"S;C"044%3>?@ABC?@>;"=;"SJB?@>?"0./D"E9FF";G"9)H#%@+#/-)+#I0#.-*Z>01+)#Y<+Y#>2;+bc0Y#I0#>-,;+#I2Y1l,.2+#'-.m#Z)0.2Y+#I2;21+)#-#.nI2;-#I0#<*+#-Z0)+I-)+#o<0#Z)0Y10#0Y10#Y0)'2b-#,+#Y<+#)0;2=-%#?-,/0b+#1-I-Y#0#\+b+#Y<+#0Y.->/+B  !"#$%&''#$%&#7# -I-#-#9)+Y2>#p4G#7# 0>0\q,2.+#7# -I-#-#9)+Y2>#p64#7#?>+)-#7# -I-#-#9)+Y2>#pR4# 0>0*+)#7# -I-#-#9)+Y2>#p4D#7#L2#7#$83#8P3#$?3#P$3#"$3#9&3#$83#"M3#ML3#PA#p5G#7#W2Z^+r#7#?nI2;-#,+.2-,+>#DRp#46#7#&>;+)#7#"M#gY01-)#Rh3#$8#gY01-)#RRh3#"$#gY01-)#66h3#ML#gY01-)#6Gh3#pV4#7#!8#?LP8#7# -I-#-#9)+Y2>#pHG#7# 0>0.-*#FG#7#?nI2;-#,+.2-,+>#FG3#pDV#7#?+*_)2I;0#7#$8#gY01-)#R4hp#6F#7#!Q #9)+Y2>#7#$83#PA3#"M3#8P3#P$#p#8P76D#7#$0).-*10>9+,.-Y#.-,'0,2+I-YB#s#9&$&#7#9+,.-#I+#&*+Jq,2+#s#9+,.-#I-#@-)I0Y10#s#9&@($ ($#t#9+,.-#I-#(Y1+I-#I-#(YZe)21-#$+,1-#s#$+,1+,I0)#s#9&@8&P&#t#9+,.-#I-#(Y1+I-#I-#8+)X#s#9&@($(#t#9+,.-#I-#(Y1+I-#I0#$0);2Z0#s#9P9#t#9+,.-#I0#9)+Ye>2+#s#9+,.-#!@ (P#s#O@!8P!"(#s#?(?P(Q#s#9)+I0Y.-#s#!1+a#s#9+,.-#"0).+,12>#s#9+,.-#$+)+#s# )2_+,.-#s#9&@$!?P(Q#s#9+,.--_#s#8+;NX.2>#s#9+,.-#I-#9)+Y2>#s#?+2]+#(.-,q*2.+#N0I0)+>#s#9+,)2Y<>#s#&,+10>#4RR4N+1<)+N+1<)+#I0#8+;+*0,1-B##D6DGFFR5HF !"#$%&%&'%()*+,-#"+)./01123456#7#8+)10#9#:;<+#9)+,.+#7#$=-#8+<>-7$8?@8AB#C6%D64%D64ECCCF76F#7#!%(%B#44G%FCH%CFG%44C?>20,10B#5%4FHGRCG?8NE?@8AB#4CDDCDH6CCC4GD(*2YY=-B#C6ECGE6C6C#8-Y1+;0*B#4DECGE6C6CP0\0)m,.2+B#"&!E6C#80)e-I-B#C4ECDE6C#+#RCECDE6CQ`_21-#+<1-*X12.-B#CCCCCCCV4RRG4HR5GC4G8X;2,+#6#I0#6

Pesquisei bastante e não consegui achar uma solução ainda.

A principio pelo que entendi não é possivel fazer um encode do pdf em si, por ser binario, `'rb'`, se eu só mandar fazer a leitura não da boa também.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentativas de converter:

```
print(text.encode('latin-1'))
print(text.encode('utf-8'))
print(text.encode('ISO-8859-1'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Olhei o teu código  e não a nada de errado, comparando com o que escrevi tbm não houve erro ao executar.

import PyPDF2

pdf_file = open('/home/unix-power/Documentos/Devs/PDF_/P1.pdf', 'rb')

read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)

page = read_pdf.getPage(0)

page_content = page.extractText()

pdf = page_content.encode('utf-8')

print(pdf)

Na imagem que posto que aponta o possível problema a indicação que seja econding do pdf a ser lido e não na codificação feita, já tentou passar um outro pdf diferente do qual esta trampando ?

Comment: Opa, já sim, alguns PDF faz a leitura corretamente. 
Acabei esquecendo de comentar novamente aqui, eu achei uma outra solução para o que eu precisava fazer.

Answer (score -1):

Solução que encontrei para conseguir ler o PDF sem que tenha problema:

```
import sys
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.converter import XMLConverter, HTMLConverter, TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
import io
import glob
from datetime import datetime

fp = open("C:\\repositorio\\teste_pdf\\pdf_split\\fatura.pdf", 'rb')
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
retstr = io.StringIO()
codec = 'utf-8'
laparams = LAParams()
device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
pages = PDFPage.get_pages(fp)
for page in pages:
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    data =  retstr.getvalue()
    print(data)
```